# Unable to make more than 2 columns in SQLite Android Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, listview

Why is that when i have more than 3 columns the app crashes? I tried debugging it by commenting out one column and it runs perfectly. After debugging it some more I found out that the problem might be on the 'populateListview' because I was able to run the app but now it won't display anything. Why do you think I couldn't run it with more than 3 columns?

Here's my dbAdapter:

```
// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_INGREDIENTNAME = "ingredientname";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String KEY_DETAILS = "details";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_INGREDIENTNAME, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_DETAILS};

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_INGREDIENTNAME = 1;
public static final int COL_IMAGE = 2;
public static final int COL_DETAILS = 3;

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_INGREDIENTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT"
        + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT"
        + ");";

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String ingredientname, String image, String detailsValue) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_INGREDIENTNAME, ingredientname);
    initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DETAILS, detailsValue);

    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();

    }
    return c;
}
```

Here's my populateListView Code:

```
    private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] { //DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,
            DBAdapter.KEY_INGREDIENTNAME };
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { //R.id.textViewItemNumber,
            R.id.textViewItemTask };
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTask);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

Comment: WHat is error you getting in log. Post your logs and the line that is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a comma, here:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_INGREDIENTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT"
        + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT"
        + ");";
```

It should be

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_INGREDIENTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT"
        + ");";
```

Comment: Why? It's only distraction.